# Can I update the Header, Body, or Footer of a lightning:overlayLibrary component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, modal, lightning-overlaylibrary

I have created a custom modal and I would like to update the footer of this component after the component has been created. Is there a way to do this?

```
openModal : function(component) {
    $A.createComponents([
        ["lightning:formattedText", {
            value : "Submit for Approval",
            "class" : "slds-text-heading--medium"
        }],
        ["c:SubmitForApproval",{
            "aura:id" : "modalBody",
            recordId : component.get("v.recordId"),
            isModal : true
        }],
        ["lightning:button", {
            "aura:id" : "choseSourceSelection",
            variant: "brand",
            disabled: component.get("v.continueDisabled"),
            label : "Submit Without File",
            title: "Submit Without File",
            onclick : component.getReference("c.confirmSubmission")
        }],

        ["lightning:button", {
            label : "Remove Cancel",
            title: "Remove Cancel", 
            variant: "brand",
            onclick : component.getReference("c.removeCancel")
        }],         


        ["lightning:button", {
            label : "Cancel",
            title: "Cancel", 
            variant: "brand",
            onclick : component.getReference("c.cancel")
        }]

    ], function(components, status) {
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                header: components[0],
                body: components[1], 
                footer: [components[2], components[3], components[4]],
                showCloseButton: true,
                cssClass: "",
                closeCallback: function() {
                    $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
                }
            });
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What is the error message? It does look like you're trying to set the header and footer.... what is wrong?

Comment: So this code works, however now I would like to access the footer and update the buttons.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about this:- "access the footer and update the buttons"?Where you want to access it? What do you want to update in the footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (with caveats) to the `body` and `footer`, but no to the header.

`lightning:overlayLibrary` is only responsible for placing a `body` and `footer` in your view using the modal container SLDS.

Once both `body` and `footer` are in place, you can think of them as individual lightning components (siblings in hierarchy) so normal rules of event based communication now applies.

Given that, it would be better if you fed `footer` with a `c:SubmitForApprovalFooter` and control any dynamic UI changes within that component itself. If the `footer` and/or `body` states influence each other in regards to dynamic UI changes, send application events (remember, siblings in hierarchy) from one to the other.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. I passed references for methods from the controlling component to the footer component. And it worked like a dream..